# RegEx (preg_match_all in PHP) to capture series of <tags containing numbers> up to the first alphanumeric character

Tags: php, regex

The problem here is the conflict between *numbers* and alpha*numeric* in the problem description.

Given the text:

> ＜0＞＜1＞＜2＞＜3＞＜4＞＜5＞＜6＞＜7＞＜8＞＜9＞＜10＞＜11＞＜12＞＜13＞＜14＞＜15＞＜16＞＜17＞＜18＞The
> next 11 keys can change the SWING from OFF (50%) to
> ＜19＞＜20＞＜21＞＜22＞＜23＞＜24＞＜25＞80＜26＞＜27＞＜28＞＜29＞＜30＞＜31＞＜32＞% during
> arpeggiator or sequencer operation.＜33＞＜34＞

I need to extract the following four groups:

```
＜0＞＜1＞＜2＞＜3＞＜4＞＜5＞＜6＞＜7＞＜8＞＜9＞＜10＞＜11＞＜12＞＜13＞＜14＞＜15＞＜16＞＜17＞＜18＞
＜19＞＜20＞＜21＞＜22＞＜23＞＜24＞＜25＞
＜26＞＜27＞＜28＞＜29＞＜30＞＜31＞＜32＞
＜33＞＜34＞
```

Reason: we want to display this in a much more user-friendly way as...

> [1]The next 11 keys can change the SWING from OFF (50%) to [2]80[3]%
> during arpeggiator or sequencer operation.[4]

Current code:

```
$pattern = '＜[\d＜＞' . REGSTART . REGEND . REGSTARTSQ . REGENDSQ . '\{\}]+＞';
$numberofsupertags = preg_match_all('/(' . $pattern . ')/', $source, $superchunks);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($superchunks);
echo '</pre><br>';
```

(REGSTART/REGEND/REGSTARTSQ/REGENDSQ refer to other possible pairs of symbols, like 【】 or 〖〗 etc.)

gives three groups:

```
＜0＞＜1＞＜2＞＜3＞＜4＞＜5＞＜6＞＜7＞＜8＞＜9＞＜10＞＜11＞＜12＞＜13＞＜14＞＜15＞＜16＞＜17＞＜18＞
＜19＞＜20＞＜21＞＜22＞＜23＞＜24＞＜25＞80＜26＞＜27＞＜28＞＜29＞＜30＞＜31＞＜32＞
＜33＞＜34＞
```

As you can see, the RegEx fails to take into account sequences of only numbers *between* tags.

I've tried lots of things:

```
$pattern = '([＜|' . REGSTART . REGSTARTSQ . '|\{]\d+?[＞|' . REGEND . REGENDSQ . | \}])+';
$pattern = '＜[\d＜＞' . REGSTART . REGEND . REGSTARTSQ . REGENDSQ . '\{\}]+[＞(?=\d)|＞]';
```

...but to no avail.

What is the correct solution and where do I go wrong? This looks really simple, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: The tags only contain numbers? Would a pattern like `(?:＜\d+＞)+` work? [Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/Hrk4O7/1) This can also be expanded to include your other symbol pairs (albeit not checking that they are a closed pair) [Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/eMOwSv/1).

Comment: That seems to work! But how do I implement the other symbol pairs? Replacing ＜ with [＜|\{ . REGSTART . '|' . REGSTARTSQ . ']' doesn't seem to work. And preferably, we'd need to check if the pairs are closed. I think that if I know the logic for two tag pairs (more than one), I can come up with the rest myself.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. I overlooked the second Try it out link. Must run now, but will check ASAP!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?:＜(?:{\d+}|【\d+】|〖\d+〗|\d+)＞)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfOVcN/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `＜` - a `＜` char
  - `(?:{\d+}|【\d+】|〖\d+〗|\d+)` - one of the alternatives: `{` + one or more digits + `}`, `【` + one or more digits + `】`, `〖` + one or more digits + `〗` or one or more digits
  - `＞` - a `＞` char
- `)+` - one or more times.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/E6jS1):

```php
$source = '＜0＞＜1＞＜2＞＜3＞＜4＞＜5＞＜6＞＜7＞＜8＞＜9＞＜10＞＜11＞＜12＞＜13＞＜14＞＜15＞＜16＞＜17＞＜18＞The next 11 keys can change the SWING from OFF (50%) to ＜19＞＜20＞＜21＞＜22＞＜23＞＜24＞＜25＞80＜26＞＜27＞＜28＞＜29＞＜30＞＜31＞＜32＞% during arpeggiator or sequencer operation.＜33＞＜34＞';

$cnt = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('~(?:＜(?:{\d+}|【\d+】|〖\d+〗|\d+)＞)+~u', function($m) use (&$cnt) {
    return '['. ++$cnt .']';
}, $source);
// => [1]The next 11 keys can change the SWING from OFF (50%) to [2]80[3]% during arpeggiator or sequencer operation.[4]
```